# tar fails with "/rw/internal_apps/rainbow/filebrowser-xxx/proc/29826/exe: cannot read link: No such file or directory

Tags: tar

I am trying to `tar` the system directories of a device running an embedded version of Linux but it fails. Here are the last few lines of the stderr.

```
tar: /rw/internal_apps/rainbow/filebrowser-45905a3/proc/29826/task/29826/exe: cannot read link: No such file or directory
tar: /rw/internal_apps/rainbow/filebrowser-45905a3/proc/29826/exe: cannot read link: No such file or directory
tar: /rw/internal_apps/rainbow/filebrowser-45905a3/proc/32037/task/32037/exe: cannot read link: No such file or directory
tar: /rw/internal_apps/rainbow/filebrowser-45905a3/proc/32037/exe: cannot read link: No such file or directory
tar: /rw/0/var/run/samba/nmbd/unexpected: socket ignored
tar: /rw/0/var/run/samba/unexpected: socket ignored
tar: /rw/0/var/run/ntpd.sock: socket ignored
tar: /rw/0/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: socket ignored
tar: error exit delayed from previous errors
```

There seems to be a bunch of identical errors so why doesn't `tar` give up on the first or ignores them all? It feels like `tar` accepts a few errors of a certain type but if the amount of errors is larger than a certain threshold it gives up?

I would prefer a solution that doesn't force me to exclude thousands of files manually.

Using tar from Busybox.

Update: the command I run `sudo tar -czf /tmp/1.tar / --exclude=tmp --exclude=shares --exclude=media --exclude sys --exclude kcore`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the actual `tar` command you're running. So far, we can only guess.

Comment: `tar` thinks the errors are minor and continues. In the end all possible files are tarred. You really shouldn't try to tar `/proc` filesystems or sockets.

Comment: It backs up everything it can, and lists everything it can't. You really don't want a backup system that faints at the first sight of blood.

Comment: @stoney But it doesn't continue/finish and tar everything it should tar. There are sbinm shares, sys, var and so on that come after rw.

Comment: @Panki Done, see above.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant So what do you suggest?

Comment: You should exclude at least `/proc` and `/sys` before anything else. Just search for a guy tried to tar `/proc` and ended up with some huge files "containing" the address spaces of all the running processes ;-)

Comment: Also, change the title to something significant; that warning only tells you that there were some errors before it, not what those errors were (`/proc/29826/task/29826/exe: cannot read link`), and will cause people to ignore your question out of hand. (Yes, that "error exit delayed" message from tar is stupid and confusing, but nobody is going to change it now, after long decades of service mystifying people ;-)).

Comment: @user414777 Why is that title better? It is not the error that makes tar exit nor is it a typical error.

Comment: That is *the* error that makes tar exit with a "fail" status -- please read my answer; the "error exit delayed" is only a warning/remark which doesn't say anything about the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should add at least `--exclude=proc` to that exclude list.

The [`/proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem is a synthetic one, generated on the fly as directories are walked in and files are read, and it makes no sense to "archive" it.

In particular `/proc/<pid>/exe` only exists as long as process `<pid>` is still running, and that process could exit in the time between tar actually deciding to archive it and actually doing it. Also, most "regular" files under `/proc` (e.g. `/proc/cmdline`) appear as having a zero size, and will be archived as empty files, despite having content when directly read.

> why doesn't tar give up on the first or ignores them all?

You can easily cut it short after the first errors with e.g.:

```
set -o pipefail  # optional, use it if you want to check the exit status
tar -cf ... 2>&1 | sed 5q
```

> tar accepts a few errors of a certain type but if the amount of errors is larger than a certain threshold it gives up

`tar` does no such thing. At least not GNU or busybox tar (which you're using).

> `tar: /rw/0/var/run/ntpd.sock: socket ignored`

This is only a warning and doesn't affect the exit status. But `/var/run` is usually a `tmpfs` (a file system which lives entirely in memory), so you should exclude it, too, just like `/dev`.

Comment: He is not running GNU tar. GNU tar would use a capital S in Socket.

Comment: @schily which version? the one from debian uses a lowercase `s` -- [link](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/tar/-/blob/dfsg-debian/src/create.c#L1922). The OP says that he's using busybox tar, but what I said for GNU tar also stands for busybox tar. I'll correct the GNU tar ref.

Answer (score 0):

You could analyse the logs: presumably the "sbinm" messages have different tags. (I searched for "sbinm", but I only found references to car envy.)

Eliminate messages you accept as unimportant. Redirect tar stderr to a file with `2> tar.errors`, and run it through awk.

```
awkLog='
$(NF) ~ /socket ignored/ { next; }
$(NF-1) ~ /cannot read link/ { next; }
{ ++Bad [$(NF)]; }
END { for (k in Bad) printf ("%8d %s\n", Bad[k], k); }
'
awk '-F:' "${awkLog}" tar.errors
```

That should print a count of all errors (except the ones specifically ignored).

Track down and investigate an example of each type, and decide whether to add those to the ignored list, fix the underlying issues, exclude from the archive (see user414777 comment), or something else. That may need some research, but you can post other questions if needed.

For example, both the error types in your question are due to transient files: sockets to Samba, and links to details about specific processes that happen to be running now (and in fact, seem to be cached in some browser anyway). Tar is absolutely right to exclude those: they won't be any use in about two minutes, and restoring them into a system that has moved on could break it.

Another common problem is ongoing changes to files. Tar is not a real-time snapshot: it makes a list of files to archive, then works through it. So files that have changed size or been deleted since will generate errors, and files added very recently will be missed.

Comment: Instead of filtering the error messages with awk, the OP could use the `--warning=no-file-ignored`, etc.

Comment: @user414777 Depends if the requirement is to understand the causes, or pretend they don't exist. I tend to do both, in that order, but I don't like the possibility of ignoring a "new" issue.